# Combinatorics-multinomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that: 
$$\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} \cdot (-1)^{n_2} = 1$$

The sum is over all positive integer solutions of $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n$.

Use the multinomial theorem:

$$(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^n = \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} x_3^{n_3}$$

Let $x_2 = z$, $x_1 = x_3 = 0$ and plug into the above:

$$(0 + z + 0)^n = \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} 0^{n_1} z^{n_2} 0^{n_3} = \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} z^{n_2}$$

Let $z = -1$ and plug in:

$$\sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} (-1)^{n_2}$$

But can't $n_2$ be both even and odd, so it could be either $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Note that the mistake you make is saying $0^{n_1} = 0^{n_3} = 1$ which is quite false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: From the multinomial theorem, we have

$$(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^n = \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n} \binom{n}{n_1,n_2,n_3} x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} x_3^{n_3}$$

Now try plugging in $x_1 = x_3 = 1$ and $x_2 = -1$...

Comment: Was my mistake (in original post) in letting x1 = x3 = 0? Can I let x1 = x3 = 1, which will allow the sum to = 1?

Comment: You can let $x_1 = x_3 = 0$ any time you want. It just doesn't give you what you want, neither on the left nor on the right. You want $x_1^{n_1} = 1$ and $x_3^{n_3} = 1$ and $x_2^{n_2} = (-1)^{n_2}$, so only one choice of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ is suitable.